# I want to make a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, random

As the title says I want to make a numpy array.

```
array=np.random.randint(2,size=(4,4))
```

First question, at this time I want to make code that size can be changeable. What should I do?

```
top = input("Top(k):")
```

Second question, I want to receive k value like this and send output as much as this value.
At this time, I wanna print the top k-row indexes from the weakest to the strongest (weakest:smaller number of ones) How to do it??:(

example like this.

input

```
[[1,0,0,0],
[1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0]]
```

Top(k):2

output

> > 0,2

if Top(k):4, output is

> > 0,2,3,1

Answer (score 0):

Numpy uses static arrays (it is implemented in C), you cannot change the size of a numpy array as you would with python lists. However, you can use the `numpy.ndarray` constructor  to create a numpy array from python list: `array = numpy.ndarray(my_python_array)`.

For you second answer you can use the function `sum()` of ndarray and use it like this:

```py
histogram = []
for i in range(len(array_2D)):
    # Store the row indexes as well as number of ones
    histogram.append((i, array2D[i].sum())) 

# Sort regarding the number of ones
histogram.sort(key=lambda e:e[1]) 
for index, val in histogram[:k]:
    print(index, end=" ")
```

Here array2D is the numpy array you got from user input. You should parse the user input to get a numpy array before executing this code.

Comment: I want to print only k of outputs, what should I do? For example, if k is 2, I want to express only up to the second value.

Comment: I edited my answer to best fit your question. In python you can use the following syntax to get only the first k elements (from 0 to k-1): my_array[:k]